# It's possible to remove the internal shading from a beamer rounded box?

Tags: beamer, boxes, shading

I'm trying to modify a `Beamer` template in order to have at the same time:
1) rounded boxes
2) shadows around the box
3) a defined line (without shading) between block title and block body (as in innertheme default)

First two points are easy (`\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}`), does anybody know how to solve the third problem?

Thanks

Comment: My `default` inner theme doesn't have this line.  Is there another example you're looking at?

Comment: May this question is something for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52123/beamer-increase-radius-of-circle-in-toc-and-include-subsection-bullet

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

% Disable shading between block title and block content
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading[lower.bg,upper.bg]{bmb@transition}{200cm}{color(0pt)=(lower.bg); color(4pt)=(lower.bg); color(4pt)=(upper.bg)}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Title without shading}
  Block stuff, and shadow is still shaded!
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ricky13: Is this what you have been looking for? Otherwise, could you please provide more details on what you try to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Could you explain a little what that command actually does. And any pitfalls of putting it into a custom theme file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{%
   {\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}}
}
```