# Indent subsections in Beamer's TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, indentation

Following [Beamer: increase radius of circle in TOC and include subsection bullet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52123/beamer-increase-radius-of-circle-in-toc-and-include-subsection-bullet) I set the 'subsection in toc' of Beamer by:

```
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}
 {\leavevmode\leftskip=2em$\bullet$\hskip1em\inserttocsubsection\par}
```

However, if a subsection title exceeds the current line, the new line is not indented correcty; the new line begins below the bullet and is not aligend with the first line. How can I change this?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick solution is to put the `tocsubsection` contents into a `parbox`:

```
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}
 {\leavevmode\leftskip=2em$\bullet$\hskip1em\parbox[t]{\textwidth-\leftskip-2em}{\inserttocsubsection}\vspace{2ex}\par}
```

Note that for the arithmetic to calculate the length of the `parbox`, the package `calc` is required. A little vertical space is added after the `parbox` to solve somewhat the spacing problems noted by Julian. The vertical spacing for the short subsection title is different from the one in the larger subsection titles.

[image]

Comment: that would be my solution too, although it may come to one's mind to calculate the box width by `\textwidth-\leftskip-1em`

Comment: The solution has one drawback: If you have an additional subsection in this section, the lines nearly colide/are drawn to close to each other.

Comment: @bloodworks Thanks for the suggestion. Updated answer accordingly.