# Correct indented sections in Beamer's TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, indentation

Following [Indent subsections in Beamer's TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89708/indent-subsections-in-beamers-toc) and [The LaTeX Beamer Class / Bugtracker / indentation in table of contents - ID: 2882539](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2882539&group_id=92412&atid=600660) I want to correct the behavior that if a section-title exceeds the current line, the new line is not indented correctly - the new line should be aligned with the first line (the text of it, not the bullet).

[image: example result]

Example (see above for result):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}


%% Beamer Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\useinnertheme{default}
%\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}

\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black} 

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\renewcommand{\(}{\begin{columns}}
\renewcommand{\)}{\end{columns}}
\newcommand{\<}[1]{\begin{column}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\>}{\end{column}}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

%% Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Agenda}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{\scshape This is an example for a very very long Sectiontitle bla bla bla}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{\scshape Short Title2}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default definition for the `section in toc` template with the `sections numbered` option is very simple (in the file `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`):

```
\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{sections numbered}
{\leavevmode\inserttocsectionnumber. \inserttocsection\par}
```

Define your own variation with the desired formattinf:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}


%% Beamer Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\useinnertheme{default}
%\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}

\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black} 

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{mysections numbered}
{\leavevmode\parbox[t]{2em}{\inserttocsectionnumber.}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax}{\inserttocsection}\par}

\renewcommand{\(}{\begin{columns}}
\renewcommand{\)}{\end{columns}}
\newcommand{\<}[1]{\begin{column}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\>}{\end{column}}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[mysections numbered]

%% Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Agenda}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{\scshape This is an example for a very very long Sectiontitle bla bla bla}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{\scshape Short Title2}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]