# latex beamer set circle template radius

Tags: beamer

in my opinion the circle in enumerations/the toc is too small when using the `circle` template. This is why I looked in the docs and found, one may use `[circle]{<radius>}` as template (c.f. `beameruserguide.pdf` Page 11). So I just tried it out and came up with

```tex
\documentclass[hyperref={colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true}]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[circle]{3pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{1}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{2}
\end{frame}


\section{Section3}
\begin{frame}{3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now when compiling, I get the following error:

```
mwe/main.tex:3: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.3 ...beamertemplate{subsection in toc}[circle]{3
                                                  pt}
```

I know there are some solutions out there (like this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52123/beamer-increase-radius-of-circle-in-toc-and-include-subsection-bullet)) which define new templates and so on. But somehow this seems to be dirty especially since at least according to the docs there is a way for this modification in the package/class already.

Am I doing something wrong or might this be wrong in the docs?

I also searched the template in the source code (found [here](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/33ba509325af3658f1fea60f68c3c34cca8027fc/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty#L229)) but I'm not experienced enough to say that in the code there is nothing which makes the circle radius a parameter (that I don't see it, doesn't mean that it's not there as I'm not that experienced with beamer templates).

EDIT: Tried with `pdflatex` and `lualatex` both times the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Some beamer templates are defined to take arguments, for them your code would be valid, but the circular `section in toc` template is defined without additional argument, the size is hard coded. If you want to change the size, you'll have to redefine the template:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true}]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  \leavevmode\leftskip=2ex%
  \llap{%
    \usebeamerfont*{section number projected}%
    \usebeamercolor{section number projected}%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{0ex}{1ex}{2ex}
      \color{bg}
      \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{.75ex}}{2.2ex}% <- change here
      \pgfusepath{fill}
      \pgftext[base]{\color{fg}\inserttocsectionnumber}
    \end{pgfpicture}\kern1.25ex%
  }%
  \inserttocsection\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}{1}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{2}
\end{frame}


\section{Section3}
\begin{frame}{3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]